# Git merge, discard conflicts, continue merge

Tags: git, merge

Im in situation when I have about 300 changes, and 30 conflicts. What I want is to discard all files with conflicts, and continue merge of files, without any conflict.

By discard, I mean not to merge changes to my branch in files, where is conflict.

Branch A merge into my Branch B.

File Row.jsx has conflict.

So I want to keep Row.jsx in Branch B version for now, and merge all other files from branch A. To resolve conflict later.

Comment: What do you call "discard" here? Restore them in the pre-merge state? On which parent? Maybe take a look at `git checkout [--ours|--theirs] -- <path> [<otherPath> ...]` (That being said, the overall plan sounds like a very bad idea, to be honest)

Comment: If your intent is to take care of the "discarded" conflicts later, be reminded that when you keep the merge commit, then you will then not be able to merge again.

Comment: Your "discard" is actually called "resolve", you need to manually resolve or take specific branch version of all conflicted files.

Comment: I have updated my question, hope it will help you undestand what I mean.

Answer (score 1):

> So I want to keep Row.jsx in Branch B version for now, and merge all other files from branch A.

You can do that quite easily by [using KDiff3 to resolve conflicts](https://github.com/hlovdal/git-resolve-conflict-using-kdiff3) because KDiff3 has an option to select changes from only B explicitly:

[image: "Choose B everywhere" menu option]

(Just a note on A/B/C naming in KDiff3, A is common base/ancestor, B the commit to rebase on top of (your branch B) and C the commit being rebased (your branch A)).

So for your scenario, you would resolve all other files normally (with normal 3-way merge in KDiff3) and then for `Row.jsx` you select B everywhere.

> To resolve conflict later.

This is doable, but notice however that a merge will implicit mark *everything* from the merged commits as resolved, so you cannot just do a plain re-merge again to get the changes you skipped for Row.jsx.

Comment: Unlucky im not using KDiff3, im using VS code and git command line. :/ but thank you for advice.

Comment: You can use both. I also use vscode for editing, but for handling conflicts I exclusively use KDiff3.